# Solve system of polynomials (4, second order) in C

Tags: c++, math, polynomial-math, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a system of 4 second order polynomial equations using C++. What is the **fastest** method for solving the system, and if possible, could you link or write a little pseudocode to explain it? I'm aware of solutions involving a Groebners basis or QR decomposition, but I can't find a clear description of how they work and how to implement them. Maybe helpful info about the polynomials:

- A solution(s) may exist or may not, but I am only interested in solutions in a certain range (e.g. x,y,z,t in [0,1])
- The polynomials are of the form: a + bx + cy + d*x*y = e + fz + gt + h*z*t (solving for x,y,z,t). All coefficients are unique.
- The polynomial equations come from bilinear interpolations.
- I've tried finding an exact analytic solution, but as others have posted, solving large systems of polynomials in Mathematica and otherwise is time consuming

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/192199-polynomial-root-solver-link-to-code/

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to solve a system of four polynomials - the Jenkins Traub algorithm describes how to find the root of one. How do I put the two together into an algorithm that finds the roots of the system without rewriting the four equations as one using substitution (because it's tedious)?

Comment: don't mind me, you asked without substitution. forget i commented. Though, for the record it wouldn't be hard to make a wrapper program that automated the substitution.

Comment: Ah right. Missed that. Have fun. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use the general-purpose solver [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/), written in C++. You can feed it with the [0, 1] bound constraints, it actually helps IPOPT and makes the solution procedure faster.

Does the sparsity pattern of the system change? If not, then you can probably save an initialization step. I am not 100% sure though. Either way, IPOPT is blazing fast compared to the analytic solution in Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the Numerical Recipes book (chap. 9 in the c version) that describes solutions of non-linear systems of equations. There is an online version viewable from their web site http://www.nr.com/.

As their licensing is very restrictive, probably you can look at the method and then adapt it using a library such as gsl. I did not try but this page http://na-inet.jp/na/gslsample/nonlinear_system.html gives an example on how to do that with gsl.